# How to invoke an external program in web app and get its ouput on that page?

Tags: php, web-applications

I want to invoke a program on the webpage and get it output on the webpage. Actually I have a packet sniffer in C language and I am executing it using exec commnd in php.

```
exec('sniffer');
```

but the thing is it shows an error "Unable to make file." and also I need as the program runs in background I should get an updated output, i.e. I want that as program modifies the output while running the output on the webpage should be refreshed to the current output.

For example:

When I start the program the output is  :  TCP:16

Now after 2 sec of program execution o/p changes to 'TCP:32'.

So it should refresh 'TCP:32' on the same page instead of 'TCP:16'.

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exec is not supposed to do what you want, use passthru instead.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Thanks but these both function are giving the same output, giving the immidiate output of the program but not the full output coz my program runs for quite a sometime it is not refreshing its output on webpage..